# Title formatting with titlesec

Tags: formatting, titlesec, paragraphs, bold

I am trying to format titles using `titlesec`.
Here is what I want to do:

- `\subsubsection`:

  [image]
- `\paragraph`:

  [image]

And this is my code:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block] {\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont \textsc{Section}\ \thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[\vspace{1mm}\titlerule]

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Roman{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block] {\textbf \fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}{\fontsize{14}{12} 
%\titleformat{\paragraph}[block] {\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}{\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont \theparagraph\ \textsc{.}}{1em}{}
```

For this result:
[image]
[image]

With the commented `\titleformat`:

[image]

As you can see, I have some issue having a bold text.

Does anyone know how to format `titlesec` command accordingly?

Comment: `\textbf` requires an argument. If the whole title has to be in boldface, replace it with `\bfseries`.

Comment: Great thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified code, which reproduces the initial image (probably not with the same font):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block] {\sffamily}{SECTION\ \thesubsubsection}{0.3em}{\bfseries\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}[\vskip 0.5ex \titlerule]

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*4}{*4}

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Roman{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block] {\bfseries\LARGE}{\theparagraph.}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\subsubsection{Prohibition}
 \lipsum[11]

 \paragraph{Restriction de concurrence}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly !